# Template Type is undefined

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning C++ and now I'm working with Template.

I'm trying to implement a Linked List:

**ListElement.hpp**

```
#ifndef LIST_ELEMENT_HPP_
#define LIST_ELEMENT_HPP_

template <class Type> class SingleLinkedList;

template <class Type>
class ListElement
{
public:
    ListElement(const Type element);
    ~ListElement(void);
public:
    Type val;
    ListElement* next;
};

#endif
```

**ListElement.cpp:**

```
#include "ListElement.hpp"

ListElement<Type>::ListElement(const Type element)
{
     *next = NULL;
     val = element;
}


ListElement<Type>::~ListElement(void)
{
}
```

I'm getting an Error on **ListElement.cpp** releated to `Type`: `Type is undefined`.

I have found a lot of examples about how to implement a Linked List but none using a separated hpp and cpp.

**Do you know how can I fix this error?**

Comment: The final code (class and implementation after preprocessing) all has to appear in the same file if you're not using specific instantiations in the implementation.

Comment: By not using separate source and header files? It doesn't really work when you are using templates, because the user of your template class needs the _whole_ class definition, and that includes the functions as well.

Comment: Also, your initialization of `next` in the constructor doesn't do what you expect it to! It assigns `NULL` to a _random_ location. You want `next = nullptr;` (or `next = 0;`) which sets the _pointer_ to `NULL`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Technically, you really want `: val(element), next(nullptr)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What amount of things you can learn here! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First problem:**

You need to fix the way you are defining the member functions of your class template:

```
template<typename Type> // <== ADD THIS!
ListElement<Type>::ListElement(const Type& element)
//                                       ^
//                                       And perhaps also this?
//                                       (don't forget to modify the
//                                       corresponding declaration if 
//                                       you change it)
{
     *next = NULL;
     val = element;
}
```

**Second problem:**

You should move those definitions to the same header file that contains the definition of the class template, or the linker will complain about undefined references. For more information, see [**this Q&A on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

**Third problem:**

In your constructor, you are currently causing undefined behavior by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. You shouldn't be doing:

```
*next = NULL;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Undefined Behavior! next is uninitialized and you are dereferencing it!
```

But rather:

```
next = NULL;
```

Or even better (using constructor initialization lists and C++11's `nullptr`):

```
template<typename Type>
ListElement<Type>::ListElement(const Type& element) :
    val(element),
    next(nullptr)
{
}
```

Comment: I have another question: If you set `next(nullptr)`, why do you set `*next = NULL;`?

Comment: @VansFannel: Sorry, that was the result of a bad copy-paste. You don't need to in fact, I edited the answer ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl, It could if `Type` is not default-constructible, or if that's expensive :)

Comment: @chris: But the order of initialization is the order in which the members appear in the class definition anyway ;)

Comment: @chris: Oh, forget, I think I misunderstood your point - I see what you mean :)

Comment: I don't understand why I have to add `&` here: `ListElement<Type>::ListElement(const Type element)`. Any advice?

Comment: @VansFannel: You don't have to, but it makes sense. Passing by reference would save an unnecessary copy

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - in general you cannot split declaration and implementation of template class in different files.
Secondly - before implementation should be template decl.

```
template<typename Type>
ListElement<Type>::ListElement(const Type element)
{
     next = NULL;
     val = element;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that I can't split declaration and implementation of template classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first try to add

```
template<class Type>
```

before each function in .cpp file

It wouldn't work. (Linker errors) So move all your implementation to .h file.

Then perhaps you should change

```
ListElement(const Type element);
```

to

```
ListElement(const Type &element);
```